# Install nuget packages based on compiler flags / Target framework

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

I am trying to provide my library for multiple framework versions of .NET (4.0 is relevant for this question). 

 
My library requires async/await support and therefore the nuget package "Microsoft.Bcl.Async" is required. But i only want to reference it in .NET 4.0 builds, but not in >= .NET 4.5


Are there any easy ways to accomplish this goal?

Comment: What version of visual studio are you using? The answer below requires newer versions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Install nuget packages based on compiler flags / Target framework

To resolve this issue, you could use the `PackageReference` instead of `packages.config` in project files.

`Tools`->`Options`->`NuGet Package Manager`->`General->Package Management`->`PackageReference`

Then add the nuget package to the project, we could add a `PackageReference` condition to the nuget package, like:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <!-- ... -->
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Bcl.Async" Version="1.0.168" Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net40'" />
    <!-- ... -->
</ItemGroup>
```

Check the document [Adding a PackageReference condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#adding-a-packagereference-condition) for some more details.